# onclick is being called continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, onclick

I have some HTML:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="postClick()" class="btn-simple" id="button">Solve</div>
<div id="message">
  <p></p>
</div>
<script>
  function postClick() {
    answers = ["A", "B", "C"]
    rand = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<p>" + rand + "</p>";
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'somefile.php',
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(msg) {
        if (msg) {
          window.location = msg;
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Before I click on the button the first time, everything is fine.
But once I have clicked the button, the display just randomly cycles through the answers automatically, as if I would click on the button every half second or so. What I want is a different answer displayed every time I click.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

If I log the caller of the function, via

```
arguments.callee.caller.toString()
```

it is the button click:

```
function onclick(event) { postClick() }
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce (Firefox 51). Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: show us the code in your success callback

Comment: You probably have included `postClick()` somewhere in the AJAX request where you only needed `postClick`.

Comment: I added the ajax call. msg is a new page or nothing. Searching the file for postClick() only gives the two places as mentioned above. Don't know what to tell you about not being able to reproduce.

Comment: It’s still impossible for me to reproduce. Do you have this online and can include a link?

Comment: Only locally, I'll post the link to the github repo in a second.

Comment: [link] (https://github.com/r0ehre/Box-Security/tree/master/Desktop-Website) The file in question is index.html, the function is at the bottom. Note that this is just a very quick and dirty birthday present, so don't expect super great code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, however I do not understand it.
The following script causes the event to be fired all the time.

```
<script src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/events_runner-21174b4c7273cfddc124acb0876792e0.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just analyzed the script a bit. Function `m` creates the click event and dispatches it. Function `u` sets the half-second timeout. Function `c` binds event listeners that call other functions that trigger another event listener that call some of the above functions. It’s quite confusing, because it’s been minified, but you kind of see why this script is responsible for the weird behavior. Have you copy-pasted the generated source code of the CodePen into you HTML file? Next time create an HTML template beforehand and copy-paste your JS, CSS and HTML there.